# Akka tracking when the actors finished

Tags: scala, akka

I have following code that traverses through a list of people and calls a callback for each of them in class1.

```
def syncPeople(callback: Person => _) = Future {
   person.findAll(criteria).foldLeft(0L) { (count, obj) =>
      callback(obj)
      count + 1
   } 
}
```

Callback and the call to syncPeople is in class2 and looks similar to this

```
def getActor(person: Person):ActorRef = {
  if(person.isMale) maleActor
  else femaleActor
}

def process(person: Person): Unit = {
   val workActor = getActor(person)
   workActor ! person
} //The actor does the actual work and may be quite intense

def syncPeople(process)
```

Now, I want to track the total time taken to sync all people. ie when the last workActor completes the work. I am using a third Actor: MonitorActor to keep track of start and end times. The MaleActor, FemaleActor can send messages to this when they process an individual

Whats the best way to keep track of this spawned processes?

I explored

1. Future.sequence // but the class sending the workActor the message is not an actor. so the future does not receive the message
2. keeping track of personIds when they finish, but without using a var, to accumulate the received messages in MonitorActor its not possible implement this.. and using var is not preferred way of doing things

What could be other ways of implementing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny, I'm working on a very similar problem to this at the moment.  The solution I would suggest is using [akka-fsm](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) which keeps track of state.

Essentially in something outside of your state object, do something like generate a Long that represents an id:

```
def getId(): Long = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
```

The state object when implemented correctly is immutable, so you just keep reusing this id throughout the transaction.

I know this answer is missing a lot of the implementation details but I'm still working on the implementation myself in my own code.  Hopefully after reading about akka-fsm a bit and playing with it, this answer will make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I ended up using akka-fsm.. it worked like a charm when there was a single request to syncPeople(). To handle multiple requests to syncPeople, I ended up creating an instance of FSM actor for each request and stopping it when the syncPeople finished. Not sure if thats the right approach.I didnt endup using the getId(). Can you elaborate on the approach using the Id.

Answer (score 1):

Don't demonize mutable state, it's SHARED mutable state, which causes the most of the problems. You don't have shared mutable state inside an actor, because you always talk to actorRefs and the actors process only one message at a time (no race conditions and other evil stuff). What I'm saying is, it's ok to use a `var` (unless you spawn some futures inside the actor, which mutate the `var`, because then your are back to SHARING mutable state). FSM is another solution as @devnulled suggested, but it sounds more like an overkill for your use case.