# How-to detect when Akka actors have finished?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm trying to implement a simple application where I assign different tasks to Akka actors and let them compute results independently. The problem is how-to detect when they *all* have finished the assigned job (success or failure counts) since I need to get from them computation results. What is typical approach?

I tried to use system.shutdown() to wait while all actors are done, but past this command actors are already terminated and do not respond to any messages needed in order to retrieve computational results.

Another thing I thought was to send something like JobCompleted message from worker actors to their parent. Then I could count how many messages of this kind I get back and if the count is equal to worker actors spawned we know that all of them have finished. Though I don't know what happens when failures inside actors occur. Also this approach seem to be too clunky.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knowing when akka actors are finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606505/knowing-when-akka-actors-are-finished)

Comment: You should use `ask` pattern for replies and `watch` the child actors using a parent actor itself or use the `Reaper` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Possible duplicates:

[Knowing when akka actors are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606505/knowing-when-akka-actors-are-finished)

[Akka tracking when the actors finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298997/akka-tracking-when-the-actors-finished)

---

The easiest out of the box way: use ask pattern and wait for all returned futures. Either in *for* block or via Future.sequence
(For more information see official docs)

Also, if you need to terminate right after your task is completed - there are many different approaches. For example, see this http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

Answer (score 0):

When you create the "jobs" and send them to the worker actors you can create a Future of the results by using the ask pattern.

This would look something like:

```
val myActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[WorkerActor]), "worker")

val result = (myActorRef ? SomeComputationMessage()).mapTo[Result]
```

if the actor sends its result back to the caller with `sender ! Result()` then this ask pattern will return a Future with the Result

As these are Futures of the results, you can map over them and work with them appropriately based on success/failure

http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/pattern/package.html

Answer (score 0):

I would have a co-ordinating actor that spawns the workers and then sends each a message specifying the work it is to do, building a set holding the ActorRefs for each worker. When a JobCompleted (or, if appropriate, JobFailed) message is received in the co-ordinator, accumulate the results and remove that message's sender (ie. the Worker's ActorRef) from the set. When the set is empty, all the workers have completed. The workers themselves can just call `context.stop(self)` to terminate themselves once they have sent their message.

Further semantics will depend on the specifics of the work. For example, the co-ordinator could set up a scheduled call back to itself (eg. calling `context.system.scheduler.schedule(someDelay, someDelay, self, ResendWorkOrders)` will send a ResendWorkOrders message to itself once each `someDelay` interval). When it gets that call, it can resend the work requests to each Worker left in the set (or even respawn them). When the set is empty (all workers have completed), the scheduling can be cancelled (the call to the scheduler returns a `Cancellable`). This can handle, for example, cases where there may be a failure to deliver a message to a worker (eg. in a distributed system), or where a worker can fail or error out without replying to the co-ordinator.